# How can I detect when a user closed the web page and using the browser.OpenAsync method?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

How can I detect when a user closes the web page and when he closes it, display an alert message using the viewmodel with the browser.OpenAsync method?

Comment: I don't believe there is any way to do this with the Essentials Browser.  You can always write your own page with a WebBrowser control if you need more control over the behavior

Comment: For extern Browser it's impossible to detect the user behavior , but for internal webview you can create a custom renderer and override `onCloseWindow` method  in WebChromeClient , refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165036/how-do-i-detect-when-a-webview-page-is-trying-to-close) .

Comment: You could use OnResume() (from App.xaml.cs) to be notified when the app resumed and check if the active viewModel is the one with browser.OpenAsync and do your code on that event. This approach is a more general one, if you need more specific stuff, you should probably go with your own webview, as @ColeX-MSFT suggested.

Comment: OnAppearing() is triggered after the user returns from the open browser page to the app content page.  You could simply set a boolean property to true before calling  await Browser.OpenAsync.  Then, simply check the value within OnAppearing. If true, display alert and set the property back to false.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple example Javascript.**

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    alert("Do you really want to close?");
};
```

Comment: On  cannot execute this. The question is referring to Xamarin.